# Sinon Stub/Spy Using WithArgs Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: sinon

When I specify withArgs for a sinon spy or stub, I expect the callCount to only count calls with those arguments. This doesn't seem to be happening, though.

If I run the following:

```
var mySpy = sinon.spy();
mySpy.withArgs("foo");

mySpy("bar");

expect(mySpy.callCount).to.be(0);
```

I get "expected 1 to equal 0". Am I crazy, is this a bug, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You have to add withArgs to the assertion, too, like so:

```
var mySpy = sinon.spy();
mySpy.withArgs("foo");

mySpy("bar");

expect(mySpy.withArgs("foo").callCount).to.be(0);
```

Comment: Or use a mock like so: `this.mock().withArgs("foo")` in a context that verifies mocks automatically, or you can verify them manually.

Comment: And I expect it to return a value only if certain arguments have been provided. But it seems to behave differently. Returns the value no matter what the arguments were

Comment: I meant `stub().withArgs('foo').returns('bar')`